# I want to show only that data which has date is null

Tags: php, mysql

I want to show only that data which `date` is `null`

Here is my query:

```
$Query = "SELECT att.`EmployeeCode`,emp.FullName ,emp.EmployeeID,emp.Photo,sum(TIME_TO_SEC(att.FinalTime)/60 - IFNULL(sp.TotalTimeLateMark,$TotalTimeLateMark))  OverTime
FROM `hr_tblattendancehistory`  att 
left join hr_tblemployee emp on att.EmployeeCode = emp.CardID
left join hr_tblspecialattendancesetting sp on sp.Date = att.Date 
WHERE emp.FullName!='' and att.`Date` Between '$FromDate' and '$Todate=''' and (TIME_TO_SEC(att.FinalTime)/60 -IFNULL(sp.TotalTimeLateMark,$TotalTimeLateMark))  > 0
group by att.`EmployeeCode`,emp.Photo,emp.FullName
order by SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(att.FinalTime)/60 -IFNULL(sp.TotalTimeLateMark,$TotalTimeLateMark))  DESC";
```

How can I do this ?

Comment: post post your table structure and data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your particular case you are probably looking for `IS NULL`, just like Nilesh Thakkar has pointed out. But in the `HAVING` clause:

```
SELECT * FROM YourTable A
LEFT JOIN AnotherTable B on A.DateColumn=B.DateColumn
HAVING DateColumn IS NULL;
```

That is because the selection should happen after the join, not before.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `IS NULL`

e.g.

```
SELECT * FROM YourTable WHERE DateColumn IS NULL;
```